# OpenCV - cv.remap() - getting black pixels

Tags: python, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import join, isdir
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Paths
ROOT = r'C:\Users\rotim\Documents\STEREO_VISION'
output_id = '7.jpg'


### Termination Critera, Modes
criteria_calib = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 1000, 1e-6)
params_ransac = (cv.FM_RANSAC, 2.5, 0.9)
flags_thresh = (cv.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
flags_indiv_calib = (0)
flags_stereo_calib = (cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)


def sort_id(e):
    return int(e.split('.')[0])


def rescaleROI(src, roi):
    x, y, w, h = roi
    dst = src[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return dst


file_list = [i for i in listdir(join(ROOT, 'L'))]
file_list.sort(key=sort_id)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Store computed points
objPts = []
imgPL, imgPR = [], []

imgSize = (640, 480) # (768, 1024), 1296x972


for f in file_list:
    fname = str(f)

    imgL = cv.imread(join(ROOT, 'L', fname))
    imgR = cv.imread(join(ROOT, 'R', fname))
    grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # h,w = grayL.shape
    retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, (9,6), flags=flags_thresh)
    retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, (9,6), flags=flags_thresh)

    if retL and retR:
        objPts.append(objp)
        corners2L = cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL, (5,5), (-1,-1), criteria_calib)
        imgPL.append(corners2L)
        # objPR.append(objp)
        corners2R = cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR, (5,5), (-1,-1), criteria_calib)
        imgPR.append(corners2R)
    else:
        print(f'Corners not found in {fname} (Left={retL}, Right={retR})')
        break

objPts = np.asarray(objPts, np.float32)
imgPL = np.asarray(imgPL, np.float32)
imgPR = np.asarray(imgPR, np.float32)



mse1, C1, D1, R1, T1 = cv.calibrateCamera(objPts, imgPL, imgSize, 
                        None, None, flags=flags_indiv_calib, criteria=criteria_calib)
mse2, C2, D2, R2, T2 = cv.calibrateCamera(objPts, imgPR, imgSize, 
                        None, None, flags=flags_indiv_calib, criteria=criteria_calib)

mseTotal,CL,DL,CR,DR,R,T,E,F = cv.stereoCalibrate(objPts, imgPL, imgPR, 
                        C1, D1, C2, D2, imgSize, flags=flags_stereo_calib, criteria=criteria_calib)

RL,RR,PL,PR,Q,validROIL,validROIR = cv.stereoRectify(CL, DL, CR, DR, imgSize, R, T, alpha=0, 
                                                     newImageSize=imgSize, flags=cv.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY)


''' Print critical parameters and per-view reprojection error '''
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=3)

print('CameraMatrix_L = \n{}\n\nCameraMatrix_R = \n{}\n'.format(CL, CR))
print('RotationStereo = \n{}\n\nTranslationStereo = \n{}\n'.format(R, T))
print('DistCoeffStereo_L = \n{}\n\nDistCoeffStereo_R = \n{}\n'.format(DL, DR))
print('Q = \n{}\n'.format(Q))

print(f'Left MSE: {mse1:0.6f}')
print(f'Right MSE: {mse1:0.6f}')
print(f'Overall MSE: {mseTotal:0.6f} ({len(file_list)} image pairs)\n')

labels = []

''' Rectification mapping '''
undistL, rectifL = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(CL, DL, RL, PL, imgSize, cv.CV_32FC1)
undistR, rectifR = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(CR, DR, RR, PR, imgSize, cv.CV_32FC1)


''' Preview rectification & remap '''
img1 = cv.imread(join(ROOT, 'L', output_id))
img2 = cv.imread(join(ROOT, 'R', output_id))
img1 = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img1 = cv.remap(img1, undistL, rectifL, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)
img2 = cv.remap(img2, undistR, rectifR, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)


plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
plt.subplot(221); plt.imshow(img1); plt.title('remap_L: ' + str(img1.shape))
plt.subplot(222); plt.imshow(img2); plt.title('remap_R: ' + str(img2.shape))

img11 = rescaleROI(img1, validROIL)
img22 = rescaleROI(img2, validROIR)

# dsize = (img11.shape[1], img11.shape[0])
# img22 = cv.resize(img22, dsize, interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)

### Compare rectified and remapped images
plt.subplot(223); plt.imshow(img11); plt.title('ROI_L: ' + str(img11.shape))
plt.subplot(224); plt.imshow(img22); plt.title('ROI_R: ' + str(img22.shape))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


''' Write parameters to .txt files '''
output_dir = r'Calibration_Files_expm'
prompt = input('Save parameters to "{}\\"? (y/n): '.format(output_dir))

if (prompt == 'y'):
    if not isdir(output_dir):
        mkdir(output_dir)
    # np.savetxt(r'Calibration_Files\C1.txt', C1, fmt='%.5e')   # identical to CL
    # np.savetxt(r'Calibration_Files\D1.txt', D1, fmt='%.5e')   # identical to DL
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'Q.txt'), Q, fmt='%.5e')
    # np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'FundMat.txt'), F, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'CmL.txt'), CL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'CmR.txt'), CR, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'DcL.txt'), DL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'DcR.txt'), DR, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'Rtn.txt'), R, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'Trnsl.txt'), T, fmt='%.5e')
    # np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'RtnL.txt'), R1, fmt='%.5e')  # Contains 'n' estimate arrays from 'n' images
    # np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'TrnslL.txt'), T1, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'RectifL.txt'), RL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'ProjL.txt'), PL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'ProjR.txt'), PR, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'umapL.txt'), undistL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'rmapL.txt'), rectifL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'umapR.txt'), undistR, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'rmapR.txt'), rectifR, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'ROIL.txt'), validROIL, fmt='%.5e')
    np.savetxt(join(output_dir, 'ROIR.txt'), validROIR, fmt='%.5e')
    print(f'Parameters saved to folder: [{output_dir}]')
```

I'm working on stereo vision(Computer vision). I want to calibrate my camera's but the cv.remap is giving a black image.[remap plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLGnm.png).

This is affecting img11 and img22 by not giving it any values to work with.

This is the main error below i tried fixing that lead me to find this problem

**ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity**

**OUTPUT AND ERROR SHOWN**

```
CameraMatrix_L = 
[[2756.143    0.     521.702]
 [   0.    2812.585  327.337]
 [   0.       0.       1.   ]]

CameraMatrix_R = 
[[1670.954    0.    1205.327]
 [   0.    2524.826  254.341]
 [   0.       0.       1.   ]]

RotationStereo = 
[[ 0.975  0.044 -0.217]
 [-0.031  0.998  0.062]
 [ 0.219 -0.054  0.974]]

TranslationStereo = 
[[-11.733]
 [ -2.918]
 [ 12.289]]

DistCoeffStereo_L = 
[[  -1.132 -135.598   -0.015   -0.123 6468.129]]

DistCoeffStereo_R = 
[[-3.015  2.26  -0.001 -0.877 -7.401]]

Q = 
[[    1.        0.        0.    -7785.808]
 [    0.        1.        0.      842.122]
 [    0.        0.        0.    16191.828]
 [    0.        0.        0.058    -0.   ]]

Left MSE: 0.185031
Right MSE: 0.185031
Overall MSE: 0.242667 (8 image pairs)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\rotim\desktop\stereo path planning\stereo-camera-path-planning\calibration.py", line 124, in <module>
    plt.subplot(223); plt.imshow(img11); plt.title('ROI_L: ' + str(img11.shape))

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 456, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2647, in imshow
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 456, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1412, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5488, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 724, in set_data
    if self._A.min() < 0 or high < self._A.max():

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 5701, in min
    axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs).view(type(self))

  File "C:\Users\rotim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 44, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

The sample images used
Left Sample image
[Left Camera image rotated 180 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDnV6.jpg)

Right Sample image
[Right Camera image rotated 180 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3cGn.jpg)

Please any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you share sample left and right images ?

Comment: alryt i'll share them, let me make an edit

Comment: I've added the sample images

Comment: also add the values of all the matrices (the small ones, not asking for image arrays)

Comment: alryt i'll include the whole code and the results shown

Comment: Do I need to add anything else, BTW the code isn't mine